Download a file procedure in python better than Selenium
I'm trying to download a file result from this site:
https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/documentos/registro-de-instrucciones-de-operacion-rio-sscc-energia/
And for that i use Selenium for select dates and click Download (if i wget the link get 403 error, it looks like the download link redirect to AWS S3, so i can't just use wget)
Is there a better way to do this? (i don't have experience with AWS, so i don't know how to deal with that)
My code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.coordinador.cl/operacion/documentos/registro-de-instrucciones-de-operacion-rio-sscc-energia/')
fini=driver.find_element(by='id',value='energia-inicio')
fini.click()
cal_ini=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='a.ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight')
cal_ini.click()
fini=driver.find_element(by='id',value='energia-termino')
fini.click()
cal_fin=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='a.ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight')
cal_fin.click()
downloadcsv=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,value='a.cen_btn.cen_btn-primary.download-energia')
downloadcsv.click()
time.sleep(30)
driver.close()


Just clicking the date-picker elements is not enough. You will need to provide both start and end dates

Thanks, that is done clicking the highligted date.
The script is working, i want to know if it can be done without Selenium.

Download file with wget and aria2
You can use wget with a useragent for download or use aria2 for faster downloading.



wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" -O export_energia.csv "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=export_energia_csv&fecha_inicio=2024-11-14&fecha_termino=2024-12-03&hora_inicio=03:00:00&hora_termino=23:59:59"





--user-agent="...": Set the User-Agent string to mimic a specific web browser (Google Chrome on Windows 10).

-O export_energia.csv: Saves the downloaded file as export_energia.csv.



aria2c
To install aria2c, you can follow the instructions based on your operating system:
Windows:

Download the Installer and Extract:

Download the latest aria2 releases page on GitHub and extract the downloaded file


Add to PATH (Optional):

To use aria2c you can add the folder that you extracted to system PATH links to help you.



For Linux:

Debian/Ubuntu:



sudo apt update



sudo apt install aria2





CentOS/RHEL:



sudo yum install aria2





Fedora:



sudo dnf install aria2






Command for downloading



aria2c --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" -x 16 -s 16 "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=export_energia_csv&fecha_inicio=2024-11-14&fecha_termino=2024-12-03&hora_inicio=03:00:00&hora_termino=23:59:59"





--header="User-Agent: ...": like wget use User-Agent

-x 16: Allows up to 16 connections for download.

-s 16: Splits the download into 16 segments for faster downloading.


Or just use it without -x, -s for normal download


Thanks, the wget solution gives me 403 Forbidden, but the Aria2c tool did the job!!!
